# Why does using setFocus on QCombobox have no response?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qcombobox, pyqt6

I tried using the `setFocus` method on QCombobox, but there was no response, just like I used the setFocus method on QLineEdit. I hope the focus can be on the QCombobox widget, just like when I move my mouse over it, it is highlighted. So, what should I do? Thanks. Here is my code:

```py
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.box = QComboBox()
        self.box.setFocusPolicy(Qt.FocusPolicy.WheelFocus)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.box)
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timeout)
        self.timer.start(3*1000)

    def timeout(self):
        print("timeout")
        self.box.setFocus()
```

Comment: QComboBox is a composite widget. It could be, the QComboBox is not "focus proxied" to its QLineEdit (`QComboBox::lineEdit()`) and does not accept focus by itself.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Qt6, as it affects both PyQt6 and PySide6. Everything works as expected when using PyQt5. If a line-edit is added to the example, it can be seen that the focus ***is*** shifted to the combo-box, but it isn't updated correctly. However, if the focus is shifted to the combo-box *first* by tabbing, it does update correctly. Also, if the combo-box is made editable (so that it gets its own line-edit), the example again works normally - so it does seem to be an issue with the combo-box itself.